# 500 Error: ENOENT, open 'C:\Users\Gilbert\WebstormProjects\games\views\layout.hbs

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js, webstorm

I get this error:

```
500 Error: ENOENT, open 'C:\Users\Gilbert\WebstormProjects\games\views\layout.hbs
```

but my project has no reference to this file. when trying to render a simple test page with HBS, I used a pregenerated express app that created a layout.jshtml file but deleated this file.

app.js:

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var express = require('express')
  , routes = require('./routes')
  , http = require('http')
  , path = require('path');

var app = express();

app.configure(function(){
  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
  app.use(express.favicon());
  app.use(express.logger('dev'));
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(require('less-middleware')({ src: __dirname + '/public' }));
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
});

app.configure('development', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
});

app.get('/', routes.index);

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
});
```

routes/index.js:

```
/*
* GET home page.
*/

exports.index = function(req, res){
  res.render('hi.hbs', { title: 'Express' });
};
```

views/hi.hbs:

```
<h1>IT WORKS</h1>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With HBS you must manually disable need for a layout with `layout:false` this should be done in the `view options` to make it app global.