# Using node with express and handlebars, how to change res.render layout path

Tags: layout, express, render

I can't find a way to change the path for the layout.

```
_config.viewsFolder = __dirname + '/views/';

var layout = _config.viewsFolder + 'layout';

res.render(_config.viewsFolder + template, {
    data: data,
    layout: layout
});
```

The path is okey:

```
/Users/user/Documents/work/noject/node_modules/noject/admin/views/layout.html
```

, but when i try to use it for layout it looks some basic path:

```
Express
500 Error: ENOENT, open '/Users/user/Documents/work/noject/views/Users/user/Documents/work/noject/node_modules/noject/admin/views/layout.html'
```

How can i change/remove this default starting path for the layout:

```
'/Users/user/Documents/work/noject/views/'
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously I'm late to this party, but this answer may be relevant for anyone else who might stumble upon this:

- [500 Error: ENOENT, open 'C:\Users\Gilbert\WebstormProjects\games\views\layout.hbs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11953778/500-error-enoent-open-c-users-gilbert-webstormprojects-games-views-layout-hb)

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.